# Problem with Scanner methods. How do I define them?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with java util Scanner and i can't find the error. I'm using Eclipse IDE. Feel free to ask if you don't understand something. I know its case sensitive, but didn't find any error.
So this is the code:

```
package TercerCas;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeraActivitat {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int nombre1;
int nombre2;
int nombre3;

Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);

nombre1= ent.nextInt();
nombre2= ent.nextInt();
nombre3= ent.nextInt();

if (nombre1>nombre2) {
if (nombre1>nombre3) {
System.out.println(nombre1);
}else {
System.out.println(nombre3);
}
}else if (nombre2>nombre3) {
System.out.println(nombre3);
}
ent.close();
}
}
```

And I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor Scanner(InputStream) is undefined
The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner
The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner
The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner
The method close() is undefined for the type Scanner

at TercerCas.PrimeraActivitat.main(PrimeraActivitat.java:15)
```

Comment: I ran your code and I didn't get any error

Comment: Your code looks sane. You're using eclipse? What jdk are you using? Does it work on command line?

Comment: I don't see any errors when running this code, is the import in your question the same as the import in your actual code?

Comment: @MeetTitan Yeah I use Eclipse, how do I check the JDK? And yeah, if I compile it with command line it works so it must be an Eclipse error.

Comment: @Mark Yeah the import is in my code.

Comment: I suggest you check your jdk and class paths within eclipse. I have moved on to intellij, but I'm sure there are articles with the help you need if you Google both.

Comment: It will help people trying to read your code if you indent it readably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner`, the type `Scanner` must be imported from `java.util.Scanner`. If you have any other Class with Name Scanner in the Same package, this error may be possible at compilation time.

Try using the fully qualified name for `Scanner` class like **`java.util.Scanner ent = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`**

Comment: Thank you a lot! There was a class named Scanner, I deleted it and it started working.

Comment: Welcome @KevinCostes

Comment: @ksadjad Even when the right `Scanner` is imported, if there's another class named `Scanner` within that same for example it will default to that. But it should also throw an error on the import `The import java.util.Scanner conflicts with a type defined in the same file`

Comment: @Mark He may have created the Scanner class in his own java.util package